# decompiled android application with only one class [DexProtector]

Tags: android, java

I'm trying to reverse engineering an android app and it's mostly for an experiment but I have a problem that I can't find a solution or even what is the problem.

I decompiled an app with JADX-gui and the whole app only have a single class named

`public class ProtectedMyApplication extends Application`

and its a really large file and my IDE can't open it well but on this class file there is a byte[] with almost 2000 lines of bytes I can't find any other classes but in the manifest file I can see the other classes

my questions are :
what is this method? and how can I study it? and is there a way to see the original smali or java code?

**UPDATE:**

app is using Dexprotecter I think and I watched the changing files and when I start the app there is two folders that will be modify one of them is the encrypted code (a .dat file with a .dex file) and there is another folder named app_outdex and I think this is the decrypted code but I can't catch the file app will remove it immediately is there any way to catch the file? I'm really so dumb in the Linux

Comment: It's been obfuscated specifically to frustrate you, maybe even in a way tuned to make decompilers produce garbage.  If you really want to study this, you'll probably need to look at the smali code and not try to turn it back into Java, at least not until you can find meaningful patterns.   Typically what is most accessible to analysis is interaction with the system libraries, which can't distorted too much without measured more extreme than usually taken.  What goal are you trying to accomplish, anyway?

Comment: @ChrisStratton hi I find the method its Dexguard Decrypting the bytes in runtime and I just want to find the way app connects to API

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to study? May be don't really need to de-obfuscate the file.

Comment: @PhoeniX hi I'm trying to see the API requests and the API calls is encrypted and i can't see it with MITM

Comment: @Amin, if you want to see only the APIs you can try to use Frida framework for example to check what is going on. It can also help you to dump the DEX file in case it was wholly encrypted and loaded during runtime - www.frida.re

Comment: @PhoeniX hi again I figured it out the app is using Dexprotecter I think and I watched the changing files and when I start the app there is two folders that will be modify one of them is the code (a .dat file with a .dex file) and there is another folder named app_outdex and I think this is the decrypted code but I can't catch the file app will remove it immediately is there any advice you can help me with?

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you please see my update question?

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are actually trying to accomplish in a way specific enough for anyone can help you.   What API, **exactly**???

Comment: @ChrisStratton the API app using for the communicate with the server but I can't use MITM apps like Charles i need to have the code

Comment: Again, **exactly which one**???  What does your analysis of the encrypted traffic (especially during setup handshake) suggest it might be using?  What platform APIs or mechanisms does it interact with to do so?  And what in the end is your actual goal which you hope to achieve by intercepting this???

Comment: @ChrisStratton its an experiment and I want to know how the app is loading views dynamically from API but this app is using SSL pinning and I can't user Charles and I don't know the mechanisms because i don't have the code nor cant use Charles

Comment: How does it accomplish networking?  What SSL implementation is it using?  How do you actually *know* it uses pinning?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the code is packed and I can't see the SSL implementation but I know the app is using SSL pinning because it won't work with Charles and Charles certificate I just need the code to find out answers but I can't because I can't catch the file in app_outdex folder

Comment: @Amit, use Frida to hook unlink/remove API call to backup the file that is being removed.